# RAID 5 Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, software-raid, raid-5

Rev 1. - Provided Screenshot for Further Clarification.

When I convert my storage drive from a basic to a dynamic disk in Windows 10, using diskpart.exe, there is one partition but no volume to go with it.  If I create a simple volume and try to retain the partition to that volume, another partition appears.  This is what will keep taking place with each simple volume created.  Is this normal and if so, how do you create a RAID 5 array on a single hard drive in diskpart.exe using just the one disk or do you have to have 3 separate physical disks?  Also, can USB thumb drives be used for one or more of the three required disks?

Note:  For clarity, please see the screenshot below where Windows is indicating a RAID 5 array exists and is denoted with the cyan color.  At the time I snapped this screen shot, I had an external storage drive attached and only one internal drive attached.

[image]

Comment: “how do you create a RAID 5 array on a single hard drive in diskpart.exe using just the one disk” – You do not. The ID is for independent disks. I recommend you stop and reconsider what you’re actually trying to achieve.

Comment: You want at least 3 separate disks.  A RAID5 volume on a single drive serves no purpose and be a huge performance hit.  Ideally, the HDDs be the same size and speed.  A thumb drive is not a good idea for RAID5.  RAID5 is really not a good idea any longer if you're using large HDDs, SSDs would be an exception.

Comment: I'm not asking the question because this is something that I want to do, I am asking because of a malware infection I have and I am trying to figure out why it keeps coming back even after formatting and reinstalling the OS.  There is also a zero byte partition on every USB of mine that I can not delete no matter what I do and I believe that is tied into the puzzle amongst other indicators I've seen.  Just looking for more understanding.

Comment: I believe it may setup the RAID config over a LAN or PAN it is also setting and using disks on multiple PCs to form the array but I'm not a 100% on these theories.  My thought process was wondering if one could set up a few VHD's and make the array that way.  I'm just not familiar enough with using dynamic disks and couldn't get it to work myself when I tried.

Comment: “it may setup the RAID config over a LAN or PAN” – No. However, all that is an entirely different question, which you could ask separately.

Answer (score 0):

> ...how do you create a RAID 5 array on a single hard drive in
>   diskpart.exe using just the one disk...

You don't. RAID 5 [requires](https://dl.acm.org/ft_gateway.cfm?id=176981&ftid=35638&dwn=1&CFID=110937223&CFTOKEN=a26e377dea75ea63-ACF3607D-F246-DB6E-D095D43BA001E810) [at](https://www.vantagetech.com/faq/raid-5-recovery-faq.html) [least](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19477-01/820-1847-20/appendixf.html#50515995_98008) [three](https://linuxacademy.com/blog/linux/raid-explained/) [drives](https://www.techrepublic.com/blog/the-enterprise-cloud/raid-50-offers-a-balance-of-performance-storage-capacity-and-data-integrity/). It uses block-level striping with parity information distributed among the multiple drives.

> ...can USB thumb drives be used for one or more of the three required disks?

Any RAID worth its salt requires multiple SATA, SAS, or NVMe drives. Using a USB-attached storage drive is bad news, because of the slowness of the USB interface, and the high failure probability of consumer-grade USB-attached flash drive devices.

Since SSDs are now more reliable than HDDs, as well as significantly faster and at [record low prices](https://www.google.com/search?q=MZ-76P512BW&source=lnms&tbm=shop&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj1m5X2uc3gAhXnilQKHe-oA9sQ_AUIDigB&biw=1229&bih=578), please consider internal SATA3 or NVMe SSDs.

Comment: I'm not looking to create a RAID 5 array for my own personal use but to understand what has been done by malware, which is on my PC's.  I have provided a screen shot to the original posted question with Rev. 1, showing that Windows is recognizing a RAID-5 array but I only have two disks connected to the machine and one is via a SSD in an external, portable enclosure which connects via USB.  Will you please clarify your statement that RAID 5 "requires at least three disks"?

Comment: Clarification provided by five authoritative sources linked in first sentence.